# Why can't set `document.getElementById` to be global variable?

Tags: javascript

For the code structure here

```
var mydo=sessionStorage.getItem("action");
function to_delete(){
    var _table=document.getElementById("showTable");
    //omit
    }
window.onload=function(){
    to_delete();
    }
```

I get desired result.
Now rewrite the code structure as below:

```
var mydo=sessionStorage.getItem("action");
var _table=document.getElementById("showTable");
function to_delete(){
    //omit
    }
window.onload=function(){
    to_delete();
    }
```

An error occur,  `TypeError: _table is null`.
Why can't set `document.getElementById` to be global variable?

Comment: It's not about it being global. You are trying to set the variable before the element is created. That's why you need to wait for onload.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your rewrite `var _table=document.getElementById("showTable");` runs before the document loads so the element does not exist.

Instead declare the global `var _table;` outside the function and assign to it in the load event.

Comment: Or place the script at the end of the page body (or right after the element definition)